# SQL injection protection in select script?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-injection

I am learning about sql injections and wondering if this specific script is susceptible. It is only a "Select" script which does have a "execute" command.

```
<?php
$dude = $_GET["va"];

$aj = "blocked";
$bj = "blocked";
$username_Database = "blocked";
$password_Database = "blocked";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$aj;dbname=$bj", $username_Database, $password_Database);
$sql = 'SELECT her, fac FROM servercheck WHERE man = ?';
$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$params = array( $dude);
$q->execute( $params );
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$r = $doc->createElement("himm" );
$doc->appendChild( $r );
foreach ( $q->fetchAll() as $row) {
   $e = $doc->createElement( "himm" );
    $e->setAttribute( 'her', $row['her'] );
 $e->setAttribute( 'fa', $row['fac'] );
    $r->appendChild( $e );      
}
print $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Sql injection is a problem when you expect some user input as parameter value. In this example you are defining the parameter value.

Comment: SQL injection can occur anytime you merge *user supplied values* in any sort of SQL query without taking proper precautions. You are using a parameterised query instead of directly putting the value into the string, so you're doing it right. See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) if you don't know how SQL injection happens.

Comment: Interesting...so if I update the question to make the $dude variable as a GET command as I have just done, it would not be?

Comment: I think the root problem is that you've heard about SQL injection and you're concerned about it but you don't really understand what it is. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is a surprisingly good resource to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using PDO prepared statements. Avoiding SQL injection is one of the main purposes for their use. Your code is good.

Comment: hmmmm....I see. I've updated the question to include a $_GET as a variable. You are saying that it is now susceptible?

Comment: @user2495313, I've updated my answer to reflect your change. Your code is actually just fine.